# "I won't be the ____ of the town." - what goes in the blank?

Tags: word-request

> I won't be the ____ of the town.

This is a phrase that I’ve heard a lot when a person is about to be shamed publicly but I just can't remember what word it was.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be talking about the expression [**to be the talk of the town**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-the-talk-of-the-town), but I don't think it implies that if you're the talk of the town, there's necessarily shame involved. It simply means that people are talking about you because you have suddenly become famous or infamous in a certain respect due to some recent event involving you.

Example:

> I'm a very low-profile person and I don't what people to know that I'm actually a millionaire. I don't want to be **the talk of the town**.

Answer (score 1):

I won't be the "laugh" of the town. Or "laughing stock"

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.